# How can you access individual values in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE section of an INSERT INTO statement in SurrealDB?

Tags: surrealdb

How can you access individual values in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE section of an INSERT INTO statement in SurrealDB?

In SQL you can access it with the VALUES operator in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as shown here:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, email)
VALUES (1, 'new_user', 'new@example.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    email = VALUES(email);
```

Is there a way to do the same in SurrealDB?

I tried to do it with the VALUES operator as you can in SQL. I was however not able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can see the example from the [Insert Statement](https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/statements/insert) documentation:

```
INSERT INTO product (name, url) VALUES ('Salesforce', 'salesforce.com') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tags += 'crm';
```

So your Insert statement would look like:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, email)
VALUES (1, 'new_user', 'new@example.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    email = 'newemail@example.com';
```

Comment: Allow me to clarify my request further.

I'm aiming to retrieve the values from the current iteration of the `VALUES (...)` clause. Here is a more detailed version of my example:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (id, username, email)
VALUES (1, 'new_user', 'new@example.com'), (2, 'new_user2', 'new2@example.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    email = VALUES(email);
```

Here I'm interested in extracting the email values, specifically 1. iteration 
 "new@example.com" and 2. iteration "new2@example.com"
The challenge lies in accessing individual values from each set of values being inserted.